# How to display a rectangular image inside a circle using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am given a rectangular picture of width=300px and height=300px.

I want to show this picture inside a circle and came up with the following CSS:

```
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

The issue that I am having is that the picture doesn't really seem to fit nicely inside the circle. It seems way to big and I think that's because the circular form is cropping off parts of the image. So, how could I avoid this? I guess I could simply upload a smaller image. An image of size 200px x 200px, however, would likely be distorted since the circle is too big for it and thus the image would be enlarged.

Any suggestions?

Here is an example of the picture I am adding:

[image: rectangular]

And here it is in a circle:

[image: circular]

Comment: Try messing around with `clip-path: circle();` to get what you want.

Comment: I think you need to add an `object-fit: cover` for the img. Can you add a snippet with current example?

Comment: @Anton: thx for your comment! I have added an example picture. I have tried out your suggestion but it doesn't really seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a background image, which gives you more control over how it sits in its container (in this case a `<div>`).

You can set the background size and position to accommodate a non-symmetric image such as yours.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/z7YIJI6.png);
  background-size: 80% 80%;
  background-position: 50% 70%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Results:

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggestion using `<div>` as wrapper:

```css
img {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 45px;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWAqE.png">
</div>
```